# Problems in monitoring file age with nagios (command substitution in filename)

Tags: bash, nagios

In my current nagios installation I check for the existence of a remote backup through NRPE. In particular, my remote nrpe.cfg (on a Ubuntu 8.x) is:

```
command[check_zimbra_backup]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_file_age -f \\
/backupdir/zimbra_backup-$(date +%a).tar.gz -w 518400 -c 86400
```

Running the command locally returned OK:

```
$ sudo su -m nagios -c "/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_file_age -f \\
/backupdir/zimbra_backup-$(date +%a).tar.gz -w 518400 -c 86400 "
FILE_AGE OK: /backupdir/zimbra_backup-Sun.tar.gz is 47661 seconds old and 10863637475 bytes
```

However, my logs showed CRITICAL:

```
nagios: SERVICE NOTIFICATION: zimbra backups;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;
FILE_AGE CRITICAL: /backupdir/zimbra_backup-Sun.tar.gz is 22373 seconds old and 10863637475 bytes
```

Notice how it returns a critical state depsite the fact that the number of seconds reported (22373) is smaller than the warning parameters (86400s, or 24 hours).

The interesting bit is that running the NRPE plugin *remotely* returns something strange:

```
$ sudo su -m _nagios -c "/usr/local/libexec/nagios/check_nrpe -H HOST \\ 
-c check_zimbra_backup"
FILE_AGE CRITICAL: /backupdir/zimbra_backup-Sun.tar.gz is 23611 seconds old and 10863637475 bytes
ҷ?Oڷ`xڷ
```

Notice the last line, which looks like some sort of garbled output.

The `check_file_age` plugin is version `v1750 (nagios-plugins 1.4.11)`

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change the command substitution from

```
[...]zimbra_backup-$(date +%a).tar.gz
```

to

```
[...]zimbra_backup-`date +%a`.tar.gz
```

Looks like nagios performs some odd command substitution when it encounters a `$` sign.